# Dynamic casting in hierarchy

Tags: oop, inheritance, casting, system-verilog, uvm

Quoting SV LRM.

> It is always legal to assign an expression of subclass type to a
>   variable of a class type higher in the inheritance tree (a superclass
>   or ancestor of the expression type). It shall be illegal to directly
>   assign a variable of a superclass type to a variable of one of its
>   subclass types. However, $cast may be used to assign a superclass
>   handle to a variable of a subclass type provided the superclass handle
>   refers to an object that is assignment compatible with the subclass
>   variable.

When are the scenarios that the casting would fail when we try to assign super class instance to sub class instance? I understand whenever we try to cast two instances that are non-compatible with each other, casting would fail. Would casting fail anytime if they fall under same hierarchical tree? If so, may I know when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never make assignments to a class instance - you make assignments to a variable with a class type. The distinction is subtle but its important to know the difference between a class type and how that applies to a class variable and class instance.

The situation the LRM refers to is this

```
class A; endclass
class B extends A; endclass
class C extends A; endclass

A a_h;
B b_h;
C c_h;

b_h = new;
a_h = b_h; // always legal to go up the inheritance tree
$cast(b_h, a_h); // $cast required - will succeed
$cast(c_h, a_h); // $cast required - will fail
```

The second $cast fails because a_h holds a handle to a class instance of type B and is trying to assign it to a class variable of type C. This code is very simple but in a larger environment, it's not always easy to know what instance is being held in a_h and SystemVerilog requires a run-time check.

Comment: So, should class casting be only done with dynamic casting?

Comment: @user1978273, No.  Dynamic casting should never be used when up-casting. Must use dynamic cast for down-casting.

Comment: Thanks Dave. How do you define upcast and downcast? is it based on the hierarchy or specifications in class definition?

Comment: See http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/what-is-upcasting-and-downcasting-in-java and https://verificationacademy.com/sessions/inheritance-and-polymorphism